# Magento Error (ReflectionException): Class Unirgy\DropshipMicrosite\Helper\ProtectedCode does not exist

Tags: magento2

When I run my Magento 2 store, I get a white page with a whole lot of text, and then at the bottom I have this error. The Unirgy modules have cause us a lot of headaches so far. Does anyone know what's going on here?

```
1 exception(s): Exception #0 (ReflectionException): 
Class Unirgy\DropshipMicrosite\Helper\ProtectedCode
does not exist Exception #0 (ReflectionException): 
Class Unirgy\DropshipMicrosite\Helper\ProtectedCode does not exist

#1 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() called 
at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:54]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition
\Runtime->getParameters() called at [vendor/magento/framework
/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:48]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic
\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework
/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at 
[app/code/Unirgy/Dropship/Helper/Data.php:2590]
#5 Unirgy\Dropship\Helper\Data->getObj() called at [app/code/Unirgy
/DropshipMicrosite/Helper/Data.php:123]
#6 Unirgy\DropshipMicrosite\Helper\Data->_msHlpPr() called at 
[app/code/Unirgy/DropshipMicrosite/Helper/Data.php:155]
#7 Unirgy\DropshipMicrosite\Helper\Data->getCurrentVendor() called at 
[app/code/Unirgy/DropshipMicrosite/Plugin/AppHttp.php:23]
#8 Unirgy\DropshipMicrosite\Plugin\AppHttp->beforeLaunch() called at 
[vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:121]
#9 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework
\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework
/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#10 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called 
at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:23]
#11 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at 
[vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:263]
#12 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at 
[pub/index.php:40]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check is this file available in you module

Class Unirgy\DropshipMicrosite\Helper\ProtectedCode

or Is there any grammatical error in file name